# Determine how much memory a class uses?

Tags: .net, memory

I am trying to find a way to determine at run-time how much memory a given class is using in .NET.  Using `Marshal.SizeOf()` is out, as it only works on value types. Is there a way to check exactly how much memory a class uses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've only recently started looking into this type of thing, but i have found that memory profilers can give quite detailed information regarding instances of objects within your application.

Here are a couple that are worth trying:

- [ANTS Profiler](http://www.red-gate.com/Products/ants_profiler/index.htm)
- [.NET Memory Profiler](http://memprofiler.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I agree that a memory profiler is the easiest way to get the information you are looking for. In addition to the two previously mentioned, I recommend JetBrains [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html), which is both a performance profiler and a memory profiler.

If you want to do it yourself, and are willing to get pretty deep into the guts of the CLR, you can use the [.NET Profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404386.aspx), which is an unmanaged API that (as Microsoft says): "enables a profiler to monitor a program's execution by the common language runtime (CLR)." It's not exactly intended for casual use, but it does have an enormous amount of functionality.

Answer (score 1):

just link to related SO question:

- [sizeof() equivalent for reference types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570/sizeof-equivalent-for-reference-types)