# Is there a way to know, programatically, how much space an object is taking in memory? (.Net 2.0)

Tags: reflection, memory, .net-2.0

I would like to be able to know, in run-time in my code, how much memory a certain object is taking (a Dataset in this case, but i'm looking for a "general" solution).

Is this possible through reflection?

This is for .Net 2.0.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, so to sumarize, there is no easy way, other than using the Profiling API which is a lot of work.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is a duplicate. Check out:

- [What is the easiest way to find out how much memory an object uses in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155022/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-find-out-how-much-memory-an-object-uses-in-net)
- [Determine how much memory a class uses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51540/determine-how-much-memory-a-class-uses#51895)

Answer (score 0):

```
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int));
```

That should work too.

Comment: Not for an object, only for a struct.