# Calculate Value Types (int, float, string) Sizes In C# With Generic Method

Tags: c#, generics, types, .net-4.0, value-type

I want to write method which calculate value types size. But i can't give value  types (int, double, float) as method parameter.

```
   /*
    *When i call this method with SizeOf<int>() and 
    *then it returns 4 bytes as result.
    */
   public static int SizeOf<T>() where T : struct
   {
       return Marshal.SizeOf(default(T));
   }

   /*
    *When i call this method with TypeOf<int>() and 
    *then it returns System.Int32 as result.
    */
   public static System.Type TypeOf<T>() 
   {
       return typeof(T);
   }
```

I don't want it that way.I want to write this method as below.

```
   /*
    *When i call this method with GetSize(int) and 
    *then it returns error like "Invalid expression term 'int'".
    */
   public static int GetSize(System.Type type)
   {
       return Marshal.SizeOf(type);
   }
```

So how can i pass value types (int, double, float, char ..) to method parameters to calculate it's size as generic.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to get byte size of type in generic list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7255951/how-to-get-byte-size-of-type-in-generic-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get an error for `GetSize(int)` is that `int` is not a value. You need to use `typeof` like so: `GetSize(typeof(int))`, or if you have an instance then: `GetSize(myInt.GetType())`.

Answer (score 1):

Your existing code just works:

```
public static int GetSize(System.Type type)
{
    return Marshal.SizeOf(type);
}
```

Not sure where that error is coming from that you posted but not from this. If you want to you can make this generic:

```
public static int GetSize<T>()
{
    return Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(T));
}
```

Comment: It appears the mystery about OPs error message is due to calling `GetSize(int)` instead of `GetSize(typeof(int))`

Comment: Has he posted the code it would have been obvious. Good guess.