# How do I determine how big a data type is in .NET?

Tags: c#, memory, types

I would like to deepen my understanding of data types and want to know how I can determine how big a data type is. I'm hoping the journey to the answer uncovers other unknowns.

I know that in .NET, a byte is an 8-bit unsigned integer, but only because I've read about it. If I have a very simple console app like the following:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
byte b = 1;
}
```

How can I tell in Visual Studio, how big the data structure of 'b' is? I see that there are some Memory diagnostic windows but it only says that they're unable to evaluate the expression when I step over the assignment of b. I have the Disassembly window open and can see the mov op...

```
mov         dword ptr [ebp-40h],1
```

... but not sure what the information means. I'm thinking that dword is hinting at the size and perhaps ptr ebp-40h is pointing to an address. Is there a way I can see all of the addresses in Visual Studio and perhaps glean the size by looking at the range?

I know these are tough questions to answer in a short forum like this but thanks for any help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `sizeof(T)` to get the size of primitive value types and non-reference types. For other types, it can be very difficult to obtain the size, because reference types generally do not have a fixed size.

This can be a complex issue outside simple types (per the discussion below), but generally, if the size of a type is not defined explicitly by its data structures because it is itself a reference type, or it is a structure that contains reference types, then there is no way to calculate storage (since it is, by definition, not fixed).

Comment: Your answer is worded very poorly/misleadingly... it's incorrect as written (although people who already know the answer can see what you meant).

Comment: It implies that if you embed a reference type inside a value type, then it'll have a fixed size.

Comment: Huh? How do you embed a reference type in a value type?

Comment: `struct MyValueType { object o; }` --> `sizeof(MyValueType)`?

Comment: Furthermore, not only will that not have a fixed size, but it *still* wouldn't *even if* you were simply embedding "primitive" types: `struct S { IntPtr p; }` certainly has a size (both managed and unmanaged), and it's not a fixed size either.

Comment: OK, fair enough. I was trying to answer in as simple a way as possible since he was asking how to get the size of a primitive type, but I've updated it more explicitly.

Comment: Again, the second problem is still there -- `IntPtr` doesn't have a fixed size. The issue is a bit more subtle than you're thinking/implying -- it has **nothing** to do with whether the size is fixed. It has to do whether the type is managed or unmanaged, and whether it's blittable.

Comment: Perhaps you should post a detailed answer that explains the nuances of platform-specific types? I believe that accuracy is important, but the OP was basically asking how to get the size of a `byte`. The answer he's looking for is, really, `sizeof`, and I tried (and failed) to explain in a few words why it wouldn't always work. I'll upvote a better answer.

Comment: Yea I did that a few minutes ago. :P

Comment: jamietre, this is exactly what I was looking for, thank you. Mehrdad, thank you for being thorough, I now know there's more to look out and will keep going.

Comment: @Mehrdad, you definitely deserve this one. But I need the rep more :)

Answer (score 6):

**tl;dr:** `sizeof(YourType)` should give you "the answer", but `Marshal.SizeOf` may be more appropriate.

#### Explanation:

That doesn't *always* work. C# doesn't like you breaking its abstraction barrier, so it *only* lets you find the "size" of a structure if the structure *has the same size* in managed and unmanaged code (or, more accurately, is "blittable"). Otherwise, C# claims, "why do you care about the managed size? It's useless to you", and doesn't let you take the `sizeof` of a managed type.

There are ways to get around this (through direct MSIL generation), but if you in fact want the size of the *unmanaged* representation of the same object, then you probably want to use `Marshal.SizeOf` instead. `sizeof` is actually not as useful as it seems -- it's just more handy.

Comment: Thank you for this Mehrdad as well. I found this article to be helful in explaing this, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/97711/sizeof-vs-Marshal-SizeOf. I'm not doing any unmanaged development, this was purely me trying to shake the .NET helping hand away.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a hardcore [SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) option, which will give you a true value for the size of an object.

Use `!ObjSize` command

```
==Immediate Window==
.load sos
!ObjSize <address>
```

You may need to poke around to get the address of the object. Check the `!Dump*` commands, like `!DumpHeap` and `!DumpStack`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i understand it well, but there's an operator [sizeof()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

```
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(byte));
```

There's also an answer related to reference types: [Getting the size of a field in bytes with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c-sharp#207605)

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that what you're asking for is how much memory a certain data type consumes? I would use the sizeof() method, so for:

```
int a = 2;
```

You could find how much space an int takes up with:

```
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(int);
```