# How to write a caching algorithm based on object size?

Tags: c#, algorithm, caching, memory-management, size

I'm trying to write a couple of caching algorithms but currently I'm stuck on an algorithm based on the size of an object in cache.

Based on the previous [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c-sharp#207605), I draw the conclusion that there is no good way to get the size of an object. So how is an algorithm based on object size supposed to work?

Comment: Is serialization an option? If yes, then it could be; Serialize -> Get Number of Bytes -> Your Cache Algo

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do it using size of an object, at least not to the very nitty-gritty precision.

Your options are:

- Use an object size estimate (such as based on the serialised object size) - this might be quite slow, inefficient and only roughly accurate
- Use some sort of a counter as an indicator of object size, such as when you mutate an object, you increment or decrement a counter to reflect the size of a change
- Use another criteria for caching, such as time when an object was inserted into a cache or frequency of access requests made to the object