# sizeof() operator for types

Tags: c#, .net

I would normally do this in my C++ code:

```
int variable = 10;
int sizeOfVariable = sizeof(variable);   //Returns 4 for 32-bit process
```

But that doesn't seem to work for C#. Is there an analog?

Comment: The size of an `int` is *always* 32-bits in C#. This is because `int` is an alias for `System.Int32` and `System.Int32` is 32-bits by definition and that will *never* change. Period, end of story.

Comment: @Jason and isn't that glorious?!

Comment: @Jason: I'm obviously not using it in that specific form.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting the size of a field in bytes with C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c-sharp)

Comment: @Jason: The point is get the size of `variable` directly, without referencing its type so that if someone decides to change the `variable` from `int` to `short` in the future, he doesn't have to look at other places for doing the replacement.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [`sizeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf) operator in C# works only on compile-time known types, not on variables (instances).

The correct example would be

```
int variable = 10;
int sizeOfVariable = sizeof(int);
```

So probably you are looking for [`Marshal.SizeOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof) which can be used on any object instances or runtime types.

```
int variable = 10;
int sizeOfVariable = Marshal.SizeOf(variable);
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof) for more information

Comment: Thanks. I new it was easy. But just from curiosity, what does `sizeof` do?

Comment: It is used to obtain the size in bytes for an type. The type should be known at compile time.

Comment: `Marshal.SizeOf(object)` tells you the *unmanaged* size of an object. It is *possible* for the *unmanaged* size of an object to differ from its *managed* size. `sizeof(typename)` tells you the *managed* size of instances of the type with name `typename`. `sizeof` can *only* be applied to `typename`s that are names of *value types*. `sizeof` can *only* be used in *unsafe* code.

Comment: Please, don't use `Marshal.SizeOf()` on `bool` and `char` :-)

Comment: @xanatos why `Marshal.SizeOf` misbehaves for bool and char? Or is it actually sizeOf C# operator misbehaving? Who is correct in reporting these values. Is it somehow attributed to some factual internal representation on how they are stored in memory?

Answer (score 10):

.NET 4.0 onwards:

```
if (Environment.Is64BitProcess)
    Console.WriteLine("64-bit process");
else
    Console.WriteLine("32-bit process");
```

Older versions of .NET framework:

```
public static bool Is64BitProcess
{
    get { return IntPtr.Size == 8; }
}
```

(*From your example I'm assuming you want to do this to determine the bitness of the process, which may in fact not be what you are trying to do!)*

Comment: I am not using it to determine the bitness of the OS. I need it to know the size of a primitive variable in memory.

Answer (score 7):

There are only a few standard situations where you'll want to do it:

```
int x = sizeof(T) // where T is a generic type
```

sadly it doesn't work :-)

```
int x = Marshal.SizeOf(T) // where T is a generic type
```

it does work except for `char` and `bool` (`Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(char))` == 1 instead of 2, `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(bool))` == 4 instead of 1)

```
int x = sizeof(IntPtr);
```

it doesn't work, but you can do it as

```
int x = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(IntPtr));
```

or, better

```
int x = IntPtr.Size;
```

All the other basic types (`byte`, `sbyte`, `short`, `ushort`, `int`, `uint`, `long`, `ulong`, `float`, `double`, `decimal`, `bool`, `char`) have a fixed length, so you can do `sizeof(int)` and it will always be 4.

Comment: The wrong reporting of size of char and bool type of variables by `Marshal.SizeOf` API is actually wrong or is attributed to some factual internal representation on how they are stored in memory?

Comment: @RBT The "wrong" size is because the one returned is the size used while doing marshaling to Windows API (you ARE using `Marshal.SizeOf` :-) ). For example see [UnmanagedType.Bool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype(v=vs.80).aspx): `A 4-byte Boolean value`

Comment: Thanks for your response @xanatos. Meanwhile I had asked the very same question out of curiosity and Hans explained it beautifully. You can have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38969438/oppostie-behavior-of-marshal-sizeof-and-sizeof-operator-for-boolean-and-char-dat).

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`Marshal.SizeOf()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.sizeof%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method, or use `sizeof` in unmanaged code:

```
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(int)));
```

[This prints `4` on ideone.](http://ideone.com/hR6e7v)

Here is a [link to Eric Lippert's blog](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/13/whats-the-difference-sizeof-and-marshal-sizeof/) describing the difference between the two sizeof options.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sizeof` on user-defined structs in unsafe contexts but unlike Marshal.SizeOf it does not support boxed objects