# Send a class through UDP socket, is this the right way to convert into bytes my data?

Tags: c#, sockets, serialization

- Is my method "ToByte()" the correct way to convert my data into
  bytes, in order to be sent via Udp?
- How can I do the reverse? (Watch the "received packet constructor")
- Should I worry about the integrity of the received packet in order to
  avoid exceptions?

  ```
  public class GameDataPacket
  {
      private MultiplayerService.Command command_;
      private string nickname_;
      private float x_;
      private float y_;

      public GameDataPacket()
      {
          this.command_ = MultiplayerService.Command.Nothing;
          this.nickname_ = "noname";
          this.x_ = 0.0f;
          this.y_ = 0.0f;
      }

      // Constructor for received packet
      public GameDataPacket(byte[] data)
      {
          this.command_ = (MultiplayerService.Command)BitConverter.ToInt32(data, 0);
          // How to get those values from the RECEIVED packet?
          this.nickname_ = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, ??, ??);
          this.x_ = BitConverter.ToSingle(data, ??); 
          this.y_ = BitConverter.ToSingle(data, ??); 
      }
  ```

How I transform into bytes my informations:

```
public byte[] ToByte()
        {
            // FORMAT
            // |Command|Name|x|y|

            List<byte> result = new List<byte>();

            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)command_));
            result.AddRange(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nickname_));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(x_));
            result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(y_));

            return result.ToArray();
        }
```

Comment: Since you're doing binary serialization, you may want to investigate [protocol buffers](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).  Quick and dirty binary serialization works fine at first, but you can run into trouble in the future when classes change and you want to support backwards compatibility.  A little thought about versioning/compatibility now can save you some major headaches in the future.

Comment: Regarding whether you should check the integrity of the packet, my advice when implementing any sort of network communication is to assume that whoever sent you the packet is actively trying to crash and/or compromise your application.  Hopefully it's not actually true, but it puts you in the right mindset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the string could be any length you'll need to either send the length of the name, or add something to the packet that lets you detect the end of the string. Prefixing the length is probably the easiest and most straight forward.

Updated Constructor and To-bytes Method:

```
    // Constructor for received packet
    public GameDataPacket(byte[] data)
    {

        int packetOffset = 0;

        this.command_ = (MultiplayerService.Command)BitConverter.ToInt32(data, packetOffset);
        packetOffset += 4;

        // read the length (in bytes) of the nickname
        int nickDataLength = BitConverter.ToInt32(data, packetOffset);
        packetOffset += 4;

        // read the nick name
        this.nickname_ = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data, packetOffset, nickDataLength);
        packetOffset += nickDataLength;
        this.x_ = BitConverter.ToSingle(data,  packetOffset);
        packetOffset += 4;
        this.y_ = BitConverter.ToSingle(data,  packetOffset);
    }

    public byte[] ToByte()
    {
        // FORMAT
        // |Command|NameDataLength|Name|x|y|

        List<byte> result = new List<byte>();

        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)command_));
        byte[] nicknameBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(nickname_);
        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(nicknameBytes.Length));
        result.AddRange(nicknameBytes);
        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(x_));
        result.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(y_));

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Can you please tell me why +4? Is every block of data  4 bytes long?

Comment: @misiMe yes that's the size of the data for each type: Int32 is 4 bytes, Float/Single is 4 bytes, if you used Int64 it would be 8 bytes.  If you'd like more information on determining what that number should be check out these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039000/sizeof-operator-for-types http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173239/c-getting-size-of-a-value-type-variable-at-runtime

Comment: @misiMe Microsoft has a list of type sizes here as well: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could use `BinaryFormatter`...

```
[Serializable]
public class MyClass
{
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

// On the sending side...
var myClass = new MyClass { MyProperty = 1 };

byte[] bytes = null;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    bf.Serialize(ms, myClass);
    bytes = ms.ToArray();
}

// On the receiving side...
MyClass other = null;
using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
{
    var bf = new BinaryFormatter();
    other = (MyClass)bf.Deserialize(ms);
}
```

Comment: BinaryFormatter is horrible for pc to pc communication. It is even iffy for Interprocess communication. All assemblies involved in the entire object graph of the serialized object must be the exact same version for deserialization to work. That can mean if one of the two PC is missing a .NET framework windows update modifies `System.dll` you can't talk to each other.