# What's the difference between sizeof(T) and Unsafe.SizeOf<T>()?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, cil

First of all, a small disclaimer before the actual question:

> I know there are a lot of closed/duplicate questions regarding the difference between the `sizeof` operator and the `Marshal.SizeOf<T>` method, and I do understand the difference between the two. Here I'm talking about the `SizeOf<T>` method in the new `Unsafe` class

So, I'm not sure I understand the actual difference between these two operations, and whether there's a specific difference when using the method on a struct/class in particular.

The `sizeof` operator takes a **Type name** and returns the number of **managed bytes** it is supposed to take up when allocated (ie. an `Int32` will return 4, for example).

The `Unsafe.SizeOf<T>` method on the other hand, is implemented in IL like all the other methods in the `Unsafe` class, and looking at the code here's what it does:

```
.method public hidebysig static int32 SizeOf<T>() cil managed aggressiveinlining
{
    .custom instance void System.Runtime.Versioning.NonVersionableAttribute::.ctor() = ( 01 00 00 00 )
    .maxstack 1
    sizeof !!T
    ret
}
```

Now, if I'm not wrong, the code is just calling `sizeof !!T` which is the same as `sizeof(T)` (calling the `sizeof` operator with the type name `T`), so wouldn't the two of them be exactly equivalent?

Also, I see the method is also allocating a useless object (the `NonVersionableAttribute`) in the first line, so wouldn't that cause a small amount of memory to be heap-allocated as well?

My question is:

> Is it safe to say that the two methods are perfectly equivalent and that therefore it is just better to use the classic `sizeof` operator, as that also avoid the allocation of that attribute in the `SizeOf<T>` method? Was this `SizeOf<T>` method added to the `Unsafe` class just for convenience at this point?

Comment: The `.custom` statement just tells you that there is a custom-attribute present belonging to this method. As custom-attributes are just metadata they are not involved in a regular method call.

Comment: Just a clarification, is this a BCL class I am unaware of, or some [third party extension](https://github.com/DotNetCross/Memory.Unsafe)? You're right that it doesn't do anything, perhaps the idea was to provide a "hook" for some cross-platform wizardry in the future?

Comment: @Groo It's a new class that's been added to CoreFX I believe with .NET Core 2.0 (not exactly sure, but it's there in .NET Core 2.0 anyways).
See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe?view=netcore-2.0

Comment: This was a necessary hack to implement System.Memory.  The coreclr tracker issue [is here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/pull/15497).  A pure implementation detail, the value it returns depends on the jitter being used at runtime.  The C# compiler still rejects any attempt to get the size of a non-blittable type.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

While this method indeed just uses `sizeof` IL instruction - there is a difference with regular `sizeof` operator, because this operator cannot be applied to arbitrary types:

> Used to obtain the size in bytes for an unmanaged type. Unmanaged
>   types include the built-in types that are listed in the table that
>   follows, and also the following:
>
> Enum types
>
> Pointer types
>
> User-defined structs that do not contain any
>   fields or properties that are reference types

If you try to write analog of `Unsafe.SizeOf` - it will not work:

```
public static int SizeOf<T>()
{
    // nope, will not compile
    return sizeof(T);
}
```

So `Unsafe.SizeOf` lifts restrictions of `sizeof` operator and allow you to use IL `sizeof` instruction with arbitrary types (including reference types for which it will return size of reference).

As for attribute construct you see in IL - that does not mean attribute will be instantiated for each call - that's just IL syntax for associating attributes with various members (method in this case).

Examples:

```
public struct Test {
    public int Int1;
}

static void Main() {
    // works
    var s1 = Unsafe.SizeOf<Test>();
    // doesn't work, need to mark method with "unsafe"
    var s2 = sizeof(Test);            
}
```

Another example:

```
public struct Test {
    public int Int1;
    public string String1;
}


static unsafe void Main() {
    // works, return 16 in 64bit process - 4 for int, 4 for padding, because
    // alignment of the type is the size of its largest element, which is 8
    // and 8 for string
    var s1 = Unsafe.SizeOf<Test>();
    // doesn't work even with unsafe, 
    // cannot take size of variable of managed type "Test"
    // because Test contains field of reference type (string)
    var s2 = sizeof(Test);                        
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! It's kinda weird though that we need this method to be able to do that, I wonder why they chose not to update the C# compiler to let the `sizeof` operator do the same without that additional IL method.
Also, wait a second, shouldn't an `int` (as it's an `Int32` struct) always be 4-bytes long, even i 64-bits processes? Shouldn't the size of `Test` be 12 bytes?

Comment: @Sergio0694 yes sure, int is 4 bytes and another 4 bytes is padding, fixed that. As for why not change sizeof operator - I don't know exactly of course, but I guess this requires change to compiler and `Unsafe.SizeOf` doesn't require any changes. Plus, there was a reason in the first place to make `sizeof` work like that, so I suppose you need to really know what you are doing when using `Unsafe.SizeOf` (it's unsafe after all).

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for the additional explanation! Totally forgot about the field offset alignment, it's been a while since I last coded in C and you tend to forget about these tiny details when using a managed language ahahahah

Comment: @Sergio0694 It's called *Unsafe* for a reason. Better have a safe language and possibly unsafe API than an unsafe language alone.