# How can I get the size of an object in the HttpRuntime.Cache?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, httpruntime.cache

I am currently storing many different types of objects in the ASP.NET HttpRuntime.Cache and I was wondering if there is a way to figure out how big each object is?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at these questions:

[Getting the size of a field in bytes with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c)
[Find out the size of a .net object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324053/find-out-the-size-of-a-net-object)

In particular, look for Jon Skeet's answer in those questions. They will tell you why the number won't be accurate.

As for getting an estimate, there is no way to do that unless there are certain criteria to be met for your object.

For instance, if you have many objects in the cache, sharing references to some common object instances, serializing out one of those objects in the cache will serialize out a copy of those common objects as well, inflating the results.

Comment: Thanks - it sounds like there isn't a completely accurate way, but it might be good enough for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: @JonTackabury, what method did you go with?

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do is serialize the object to a file on disk. That should give you an idea.

This [cache manager](http://aspalliance.com/cachemanager/) from ASP Alliance might help as well

Comment: I tried the ASP Alliance tool and I get "Data could not be serialized to Xml" for most of the objects I'm interested in... Does anyone have any sample code to take arbitrary stuff from `HttpRuntime.Cache` and serialize it?