# Is there a simple way to determine type size in C#?

Tags: c#

Is there a way to say something like:

sizeof(type)? Or type.Size?

Right now I am looking at using code like:

```
if (type.Equals(typeof(int)))
    return sizeof(int);
else if (type.Equals(typeof(long)))
    return sizeof(long);
```

etc, etc, for every single data type.

There must be an cleaner solution, no?

Comment: Can you explain a reason behind what you wanna do?

Comment: Thats funny, I almost posted this exact question yesterday, but didn't have time. I need the exact same thing for using ADO.NET DbParameters. Sometimes it forces you to set DbParameter.Size, which is the size of the object in bytes. I too had a big switch statement like the one you originally posted :)

Answer (score 12):

Try Marshal.SizeOf()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s4920fa.aspx

Comment: This looks like it gets the size, in memory, of a specific object or value, which isn't necessarily the same as the size of a type.

Comment: There is also a type overload.  I mistakenly linked to the Object version.  Will update shortly

Comment: Still, from the doc:

"The size returned is the actually the size of the unmanaged type. The unmanaged and managed sizes of an object can differ. For character types, the size is affected by the CharSet value applied to that class."

Depending on what the use case is, it could be misleading.

Comment: I'm not sure I following you.  Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Foo)) will have the same size every time.  Yes there can be a subtle difference between the managed and native size of a type.  But given the asker used the C# sizeof() method I'm guessing they're looking for native size.

Comment: It returns a different value for bool too:

bool boolean = true;
Type type = boolean.GetType();
Console.WriteLine(sizeof(bool));
Console.WriteLine(Marshal.SizeOf(type));

The first line will output "1", the second will output "4".

Comment: After a quick batch of tests bool appears to be the only different one.  I *believe* this is due to a difference in the marshalling decisions of C# and the Marshal class.  Bool's can be both marshal'd as a 4 byte and 1 byte structure depending on the circumstance

Comment: Link to a blog post I wrote on this subject: http://blogs.msdn.com/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/14/pinvoke-and-bool-or-should-i-say-bool.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If this is for data access, you can do type.GetTypeCode() (which is a member of IConvertible), which gives you a nice enum to switch on.

Answer (score 1):

Look at these questions:

- [Getting the size of a field in bytes with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c#207601)
- [How can I get the size of an object in the HttpRuntime.Cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/326606/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-object-in-the-httpruntimecache#326695)
- [Find out the size of a .net object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324053/find-out-the-size-of-a-net-object#324063)

In particular, read the answers left by [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet).

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you can go 
`Convert.ToString(type.MaxValue, 2).Length / 8`
?