# .NET Object size

Tags: c#, .net, memory, memory-management

What is the size of a heap-allocated Object in .net, including management overhead?  I'm assuming Objects are allocated along 4-byte boundaries, or is a different approach used?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324053/find-out-the-size-of-a-net-object

Comment: Jon B: That question is about the size of any object in .NET while this question is about the size of instances of the .NET Object class. A totally different question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

4 byte boundaries on x86. Possibly 8 byte boundaries on x64.

There's an 8 byte overhead on x86, for a type reference and a sync block. I wouldn't be surprised to find that's 12 or 16 bytes on x64.

For some reason, on x86 an instance of just `System.Object` appears to take 12 bytes, making 12 bytes the absolute minimum size possible - but a class with an `int` *also* takes 12 bytes. I've no idea why this is the case.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to answer the high AND low level questions so well. I'm retaging with a new tag: stump-the-skeet.
In this case, this question is the stump-the-skeet:fail.

Comment: That tag didn't last long.  ;-)

Comment: figured.  Thought I'd try. :)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on a machine, on 32 bit machine it is usually 4-bytes. However, on 64 bit box, it is 8-bytes, and so on.

Comment: I think you're talking about the size of a *reference* rather than the object overhead itself.