# Load SOS extension for debugging

Tags: .net, debugging, memory-leaks

I'm trying to load SOS extension in visual studio 2010 (.Net framework 4) in a vb.net app without success.

First i found the following [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jfoscoding/archive/2006/05/03/588974.aspx) suggesting that I type *"!load sos*" in the immidiate window. It resulted in the following error message:

```
Error during command: extension C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\sos.dll could not load (error 193)
```

Next I found an [article](http://debuggingblog.com/wp/2009/07/07/windbg-extension-sos-in-clr-40net-framework-40-ctp-net-runtime-dll-renamed-and-sos-commands-just-got-richer/) suggesting *.loadby sos clr*. That gave me the following error:

```
Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses.
```

How do I load it?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are running on a 64-bit version of Windows.  Debugging with sos.dll is not possible when your program is 64-bit as well, Visual Studio is a 32-bit process.

Fix: Project + Properties, Compile tab, scroll down, Advanced, Target CPU = x86.

Comment: +1 for the answer. For solution: wouldn't it be better to select the target via the active solution configuration? Your way may produces a configuration mess.

Comment: No, definitely not.  The solution configuration setting selection only has an effect on C++ projects.  Changing it does *not* affect the property that matters for a managed project.

Comment: Does this mean, if I set the active solution configuration to target X86 and run my target, I wont get a 32 bit process from my C# app? Hard to believe...?

Comment: @user492238 - yes, you can have such a behavior. Configuration Manager's Platform for each Project specifies the application platform. You can make a big mess there.

Comment: No, the bitness for C# code is selected by Project + Properties, Compile tab, Target platform setting.  For the EXE project.  It is **not** selected by the configuration platform.

Comment: It's actually a combination of the 2. You can configure a solution configuration to be say "x86" (or Win32) and each project to build as 32 bit in there. Another solution configuration for x64 and each project as "x64" in there. VS also allows you to mix and match project configurations inside a solution configuration. So in the "x86" one above you could potenially have "Any CPU" project configuration or even x64.

Comment: This is one of the Great Myths of project configurations.  The name of the solution's platform has nothing to do with it.  Only the Target platform setting matters.