# A good way to estimate/calculate object size in memory

Tags: .net

Lets say I have object Tom which has class Person.

```
Class Person

String Name
DateTime BirthDate
String Role
Int32 Salary
```

Can you give me an approximation of its memory size if it has the following values:

Name = Tom. BirthDate = 1/1/1990. Role = User. Salary = 30000

Could you also give me some insight into how the calculation was done?

Comment: See [Find out the size of a .net object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324053/find-out-the-size-of-a-net-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a true figure, use the [CLR profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx).  To do it programmatically, use [`sizeof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eahchzkf%28VS.71%29.aspx) (only works on value types). You could also do it by referencing the GC directly [like this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mab/archive/2006/04/24/582666.aspx)...

```
long StopBytes = 0;
foo myFoo;

long StartBytes = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
myFoo = new foo();
StopBytes = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
GC.KeepAlive(myFoo); // This ensure a reference to object keeps object in memory

long TotalBytes = StopBytes - StartBytes;
MessageBox.Show("Size is " + TotalBytes.ToString());
```