# how to determine the size of an object?

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, object

```
Public Class A
    Private aa As Integer
    Dim bb As Integer
    Public cc As Integer
End Class

Public Class B
    Inherits A

    Private dd As Integer
    Dim ee As Integer
    Public ff As Integer
End Class

Public Class C
    Dim oA As New A
End Class
```

what is the size of the object oA?
and what if Class A and B contain methods?(I meant the size of object)
what if inherited class B contains overridden methods?(size of object)
what if inherited class B contains variables with same name as in Class A?(size of object)

I need theoretical answer. Does those access specifiers Private,Dim,Public make any difference in allocating memory because of their different scopes?
On what basis memory is allotted for a method? etc.

Comment: Maybe this can help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324053/find-out-the-size-of-a-net-object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `oA` is a variable holding a reference, not an object; the size of a reference depends on the platform, but is generally 4 bytes on x86 and 8 bytes on x64
- the object *referenced* by `oA` is of type `A`, and has 3 integers, so the size is 12 bytes plus the standard object header
- methods do not impact object size (no matter whether they are direct or inherited)
- an instance of type `B` has 6 integers (3 directly, 3 inherited from `A`); any name overlaps do not impact the fact that they exist - so the size is 24 bytes plus the standard object header

Comment: what will be the size of object header and what will it depend on?

Comment: @dotNETbeginner see http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/object-overhead-the-hidden-.net-memory--allocation-cost/