# Getting an OutOfMemoryException while serialising to JSON?

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net

I am serializing , a `MultiDictionary<String,Object>`

[http://powercollections.codeplex.com/ to json .](http://powercollections.codeplex.com/)

It has 618 elements with elements being deeply nested ,i.e. a single Object may have several dictionary like objects in it . I am using JSON.Net

```
String json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);
```

what am i missing ?

MORE INFO: - 
This was working fine till i was using dynamic , i had to switch to MultiDictionary to allow multiple properties of the same name . It works for most cases , only when the number of items is large , it breaks .

UPDATE: -

I have been able to get a hold of the Memory consumption but cutting down on some elements that were getting added recursively to each element.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It appears that you're running into [Ciruclar Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) that is causing `OutOfMemoryException` or your objects are simply too large for your memory. Use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#DependencyCycle) to check this.

You might find useful [getting the total size of your objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324053/find-out-the-size-of-a-net-object).

Comment: is there a way of checking the circular reference ?

Comment: @ashutoshraina http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#DependencyCycle seems like the preferred tool by everyone

Answer (score 20):

Assuming you don't have Circular References - if you can't store the whole thing in memory use a StreamWriter(JsonWriter or TextWriter) in Newtonsoft v4.0.30319

```
using (TextWriter writer = File.CreateText("LocalJSONFile.JSON"))
{
    var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(writer, myObject);
}
```

Use JsonWriter if you are trying to pass the string

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);

using(JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
{
  var serializer = new JsonSerializer();
  serializer.Serialize(writer, myObject);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. After so much headache, finally your first solutions regarding TextWriter is worked. I wish, if I could vote for you 10 times.

Comment: How to pass settings? like PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects, ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize

Comment: Also without settings also, above code is failing even though i have 4 GB RAM available in my computer.

Comment: You are trying to save a setting of the function within the large object itself? I would recommend a few things - namely don't do that. Save those values in one object somewhere that is specific to the configuration and have the large JSON just be for data. If you cant do that then I would recommend having two scans of the single object, the first extracts the settings, the second processes the large JSON.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to tell without knowing the exact structure of the objects being serialized, but it's possible that, since the object graph is so big, there might be circular references somewhere (an object which points to an object which in turn points to the first object), creating an infinite loop of serialization.

**EDIT :**

You may use a tool, like [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/Features.aspx#DependencyCycle), to find out where the circular references are. Give the trial version a try.