# ajax call - outofmemory exception on returning big json string in asmx webmethod

Tags: c#, ajax, web-services, serialization

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown:
>
> at System.Text.StringBuilder.ToString() at
>   System.Web.Util.HttpEncoder.JavaScriptStringEncode(String value)    at
>   System.Web.HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(String value, Boolean
>   addDoubleQuotes)    at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeString(String
>   input, StringBuilder sb)    at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValueInternal(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.SerializeValue(Object
>   o, StringBuilder sb, Int32 depth, Hashtable objectsInUse,
>   SerializationFormat serializationFormat, MemberInfo currentMember)
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj, StringBuilder output, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Object
>   obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)    at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext
>   context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)

json string that returned is big(more than 5MB), what are the solution for this problem?

Comment: What is the value in the config file for  `<httpRuntime maxMessageLength=`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630736/getting-an-outofmemoryexception-while-serialising-to-json) SO question.

Comment: @CodingYoshi : I don't have maxMessageLength property in httpRuntime. instead maxQueryStringLength property exist but not helping.

Comment: @JeroenHeier : I already handle the problem of circuit reference. so it not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default, it is possible to send or receive 4MB of data(Maximum). If you want to send more than that, you have to change the maxMessageLength in your web.config file like below.

```
 <configuration>

  <system.web>

     <httpRuntime maxMessageLength="409600"

       executionTimeoutInSeconds="300"/>

 </system.web>

</configuration>
```

With above setting, you can send 400MB of data with maximum time of 300 seconds. After that time, your execution will get stopped as TimeOut.

Comment: @CodinngYoshi:
Server Error in '/' Application.
Configuration Error 
  Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately. 

 Parser Error Message: Unrecognized attribute 'maxMessageLength'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.
 Source File:  D:\wgd\web.config    Line:  40 

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.1586.0