# enterprise library cached object size

Tags: caching, memcached, enterprise-library

I've setup the enterprise library caching counters using Perfmon. However all I can see is number of entries in cache.

COuld someone please help me if there's way to find out the size of the cached object so that I can specify correct value for Max num of items to be cached and removed etc?

Also, what does Missed Caches really means as I see quiet large number of misses although my web application is working as expected. Do  I need to worry about this counter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enterprise Library Caching does not provide the size of the cache or the size of objects in the cache.

There are various approaches to finding the object size that you could use to try to tune the cache size.  See:

- [Find out the size of a .net object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324053/find-out-the-size-of-a-net-object)
- [How to get object size in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605621/how-to-get-object-size-in-memory)

A Cache Miss is when an item is attempted to be retrieved from the cache but the key is not found in the cache.  Usually when this happens you would add the item to the cache.  This is not usually alarming since for a cache with no backing store it will be empty at first so initially you would see cache misses but misses should decrease as the cache is loaded (unless of course items expire and are removed from the cache).