# How to find memory used by each object in a program?

Tags: c#, memory, object

How do I find out about the memory used by each object in a program?

For example : I want to know how much memory(in Kb) is used by this object "someclassinstance"..

someclass someclassinstance=new someclass();

I can see the total memory used by the application in the task manager...But Is there a way to see detailed report about memory usage for each object instance?

Note:I've tried CLR profiler..but it only shows total memory used by strings as far as i know...It does not show the memory used by each string object.

Thanks

Comment: Related:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426396/how-much-memory-does-a-c-net-object-use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CLR profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=A362781C-3870-43BE-8926-862B40AA0CD0&displaylang=en) is free and can do this. It has a learning curve, but comes with the documentation you will need.

Answer (score 2):

[.NET Memory Profiler is excellent](http://memprofiler.com/)  It's got a 14 day trial and is pretty cheap after that.  It lets you track all the instances you have, graph them and see how much memory each is taking.  It gives you a tremendous amount of insight into exactly what is happening in your application.

Answer (score 1):

[Red Gate Software](http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_profiler/index.htm) makes Ants Profiler which I believe will give you the information you want. It's decidedly non-free but there is a 15 day trial and depending on whether or not your lucky enough to have a budget for software at your job you might be able to buy it.

Answer (score 0):

The mount of memory allocated is for a `new someclass` is sizeof(someclass) rounded up; the rounding up is probabably something like sizeof(someclass) + sizeof(void*) rounded to 32.

This won't tell you what, if any, memory someclass allocates for its members.

The best way to do this might be to replace global operator new with a wrapper that records bytes allocated. Note that as alluded to above, the bytes requested are less than the bytes actually allocated, for book-keeping and alignment reasons.

This can be done in C++, I don't know about C#.

Answer (score 0):

The free, extremely powerful and fairly tricky way of doing this is with [Windbg + SOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx)

This [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/jasonz/archive/2003/10/21/53581.aspx) should be enough to start you off.

Comment: But,Please explain how or point me to a link where its explained...Thanks