# Memory usage of class instance in c#

Tags: c#, class, memory, size, instance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How much memory does a C#/.NET object use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426396/how-much-memory-does-a-c-net-object-use)

Like the title says, how can I check how much memory a class instance takes in memory in c# (webforms)

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Comment: I wonder what practical application this might have.

Comment: Who cares if it has a practical application or not. It's an interesting question. Unfortunately, a duplicate. :)

Comment: Thank you siz! So annoying when people do that. Ruins this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter ramCounter; 
ramCounter = new System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes"); 

public string getAvailableRAM()
{
      return ramCounter.NextValue() + "Mb";
}
```

Those be the tools to your disposal :D hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You can check this one - [Find size of object instance in bytes in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1128315/find-size-of-object-instance-in-bytes-in-c)