# Size of object in memory

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get object size in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605621/how-to-get-object-size-in-memory)

Is it possible to know, obviously at runtime, the memory taken by an object? How? Specifically I'd like to know the amount of RAM occupied.

Comment: Use a [memory profiler](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+memory+profiler).

Comment: There are gazillions of dupes already. Please search before posting. [How to get object size in memory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605621/how-to-get-object-size-in-memory). And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426396/how-much-memory-does-a-c-net-object-use. And also http://www.google.com/#hl=en&sclient=psy-ab&q=.net+size+of+object+in+memory&pbx=1&oq=.net+size+of+object+in+memory&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=1&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=987l6327l0l6549l29l20l0l9l9l5l2247l4909l9.7.0.3.9-1l29l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=f0b85e3c6de8b9f9&biw=1440&bih=795

Answer (score 15):

For value types use `sizeof(object value)`

For unmanaged objects use `Marshal.SizeOf(object obj)`

*Unfortunately the two above will not get you the sizes of referenced objects.*

For managed object: There is no direct way to get the size of RAM they use for managed objects, see: http://blogs.msdn.com/cbrumme/archive/2003/04/15/51326.aspx

Or alternatives:

**System.GC.GetTotalMemory**

```
long StopBytes = 0;
foo myFoo;

long StartBytes = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
myFoo = new foo();
StopBytes = System.GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
GC.KeepAlive(myFoo); // This ensure a reference to object keeps object in memory

MessageBox.Show("Size is " + ((long)(StopBytes - StartBytes)).ToString());
```

Source: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mab/archive/2006/04/24/582666.aspx

**Profiler**

Using a profiler would be the best.

Comment: it seems that result is always 0 when trying this code on List<T> or arrays?

Comment: Note: This will give inaccurate results if `new foo()` allocates other stuff, which is sometimes the case.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16273) to see the allocation size for each type (not a specific object).There are also some commercial products that can help you monitor the usage of memory of your program.JetBrains [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) and RedGate [Ants](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/) are some of them.