# How to estimate the memory size of an instance of a class (from code inspection only)

Tags: .net, memory-management, out-of-memory

In .NET/C#, I have a **class which consists of only value types**. I want to estimate how much memory large sets of objects of this class use. How to get the size of a single instance of this class?

Here's what the class contains:

- `DateTime`
- `DateTime?`
- `int` ( 4 times)
- `int?` ( 5 times)
- `Guid`

**Basically, I am looking for information on how much memory each of these types use (on a 64bit System).**

Note: I have seen [answers like this one about profiling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426412) (which does not actually answer the question there, nor mine) and this [question, without restriction to value types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/324053/find-out-the-size-of-a-net-object), so I do not consider this a duplicate.