# Is Serialization reliable for object size estimation?

Tags: c#, memory, serialization, object

I use serialization, in order to estimate the amount of memory used for an object.
I already read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426396/how-much-memory-does-a-c-net-object-use), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26570/sizeof-equivalent-for-reference-types).
So I know that it may be better to use a profiler or sizeof (for value types).

I would like to know, what is the exact difference between the serialized object and the object in memory ? In what measure is serialization reliable for object size estimation ?

I am especially interested in C# serialization mechanisms.

Comment: Binary serialization or XML? XML is going to have a /considerable/ difference while binary may be more or less accurate if you're just looking for a general estimation.

Comment: @Spencer - I'd argue that neither is accurate for this purpose...

Comment: Why is this a community wiki?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The serialized form of data is not the same as in-memory; for example, a collection/dictionary will involve multiple objects for the items, the arrays, hash-buckets/indexes, etc - but the raw data (when serialized) will *typically* be just the data - so you might see less volume when serialized.

Equally, things like `BinaryFormatter` have to include a lot of (verbose) type metadata - but in the objects it just has a (terse) type handle in the object handle - so you might see *more* data in the serialized data. Likewise, the serializer (unless it is manually optimized) needs to tokenize the individual fields - but in memory this is implicit in the offset from the objects address.

So you might get *a* number from serialization, but it is not the **same** number.

To get an accurate idea of the size of an object graph is tricky. SOS might help; otherwise, create a whole shed-load of them and divide. Crude, but it might just work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function I've used to estimate the memory cost of a managed type. It presumes that objects are allocated sequentially in memory (and not from the large-object heap) so it will not give an accurate result for objects that allocate huge arrays for example. It also does not absolutely guarantee that GC won't corrupt the answer but it makes that very unlikely.

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the memory cost of a reference type.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="type">The type for which to get the cost. It must have a
/// public parameterless constructor.</param>
/// <returns>The number of bytes occupied by a default-constructed
/// instance of the reference type, including any sub-objects it creates
/// during construction. Returns -1 if the type does not have a public
/// parameterless constructor.</returns>
public static int MemoryCost(Type type)
{
  // Make garbage collection very unlikely during the execution of this function
  GC.Collect();
  GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

  // Get the constructor and invoke it once to run JIT and any initialization code
  ConstructorInfo constr = type.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
  if (constr == null)
    return -1;
  object inst1 = constr.Invoke(null); // 

  int size;
  unsafe
  {
    // Create marker arrays and an instance of the type
    int[] a1 = new int[1];
    int[] a2 = new int[1];
    object inst2 = constr.Invoke(null);
    int[] a3 = new int[1];

    // Compute the size by determining how much was allocated in between
    // the marker arrays.
    fixed (int* p1 = a1)
    {
      fixed (int* p2 = a2)
      {
        fixed (int* p3 = a3)
        {
          size = (int)(((long)p3 - (long)p2) - ((long)p2 - (long)p1));
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return size;
}
```

Comment: Way too many assumptions here. Why not use a memory profiler?