# Session - memory size of objects

Tags: asp.net

I have a variable in the session; how do I find out its size?

Thanks

Comment: Size of what? if you want the memory size, possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426396/how-much-memory-does-a-c-net-object-use, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/324053/find-out-the-size-of-a-net-object and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/760230/is-serialization-reliable-for-object-size-estimation - Is Serialization reliable for object size estimation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int mySizeize = sizeof(myVariable);
```

will not work for reference type

or `Marshal.SizeOf Method (Object)`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3ybkfb3.aspx

Comment: Please read Jon's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207592/getting-the-size-of-a-field-in-bytes-with-c/207605#207605